# Do types in QT applications for different platforms have similar size?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, built-in-types

I created an application for Windows in C++ using QT. If I want to port it to Linux or Mac OS, will `sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(long)` change? In other words, do types in QT applications for different platforms have similar size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to stefaanv's answer, if you're worried about their  size, use `quint32` and friends. Qt guarantees them to be the same size on all supported platforms.

Check out [QtGlobal](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtglobal.html):

> The header file declares several type definitions that guarantee a specified bit-size on all platforms supported by Qt for various basic types, for example qint8 which is a signed char guaranteed to be 8-bit on all platforms supported by Qt. The header file also declares the qlonglong type definition for long long int (__int64 on Windows).
>
> Several convenience type definitions are declared: qreal for double, uchar for unsigned char, uint for unsigned int, ulong for unsigned long and ushort for unsigned short.

Or, if you want a more standard solution, there's [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h). I like using Qt all the way, because then the porting is literally just running `qmake` on a different platform.

Answer (score 7):

int and long are C++ types.  They don't have a fixed size defined by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, do types in QT
>   applications for different platforms
>   have similar size?

First of all, Qt and not QT (Quick Time).
Secondly, if you want to have several types that guarantee a specified bit-size on all platforms supported by Qt the good idea is to use typedefs from [QtGlobal](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtglobal.html). qint8, ...